# How to fix run time error '13' in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge Excel VBA  file (xlsm). It used to be able to run it without any problem. Now my co-worker runs it without any problem. But when I run it, it keeps
giving me this "Run Time Error '13'". I just installed a patch called: 
"excel2010-kb2956142-fullfile-x64-glb" on my Windows 7, 64bit machine.

Here is the code snipet:

```
iPos2 = 0
On Error Resume Next
iPos2 = Application.Match(sComponent, sBsLvlShort(), 0)
On Error GoTo 0
```

The debug stops at the line with:
Application.Match
What else can be done? I know the Excel has no problem.

Thanks for any help.

Jennifer

Comment: At a minimum, post the code from the line that is generating the error. A few lines above and below wouldn't hurt. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is `sBsLvlShort`? An array? Would a dictionary be a better choice?

Comment: It is an array with 5 items. I cannot change the code since it is legacy code not mine. It has been runing without any problem until I ran it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the Debug mode when the code "breaks".

Then, in the VBE "Immediate" pane, enter the following statement and press the <kbd>Return</kbd> key:

```
?TypeName(iPos2)
```

And tell me what it prints on the next line. Then again in the Immediate pane, enter this statement and press the <kbd>Return</kbd> key:

```
?Application.Match(sComponent, sBsLvlShort(), 0)
```

Then, tell me what is printed on the next line.

Whatever is being stored in the array is causing a mismatch with the data type associated with the `iPos2` variable.

One other possibility is that you have inadvertently enabled the option in VBE to "Break on All Errors".  In the VBE check Tools | Options | General and ensure the "Break on Unhandled Errors" option is checked. Otherwise, even errors wrapped in the `On Error Resume Next` statement will raise (the `Application.Match` function will return an error type if the value isn't found in the array).

Otherwise what is actually in this array? Have you verified this using the Locals pane to examine its contents? (If you don't know how to do this, Google will be useful!)

If it is not containing what you expect it to contain, then you need to work backwards and find the line of code that assigns to this variable, and debug from there. At that point, it seems likely it could be user error (i.e., you've provided the wrong inputs for the procedure, in which case an error is often to be expected).

Comment: Thank you very much, David! I will test it tomorrow morning.

Comment: For now I have to leave for home. And I also got another error at: another line that runs Application.Match that also involves sBsLvlShort:   iNdxGroup = Application.Match(sExpGroup, sBsLvlShort(), 0)
On Error GoTo 0

Comment: Here is what I got:            ?TypeName(ipos2)     
Integer     
?Application.Match(sComponent, sBsLvlShort(), 0)    
Error 2042

Comment: Yes, the setting is "Break on All Errors". I just switched it to "Break on unhandled errors"

Comment: After the setting change, it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: David,Thank you so much!